Difference in approach when reviewing papers vs grants
Normally, we begin our experiences as peer-reviewers by answering request from journals and conferences to review papers. In these cases, all the details are included and the quality of the science can be judged from this. But this is not the case in grants, and unlike journal and conference reviews, the results of a grant application can be associated with hundreds of thousands to millions of dollars and are decided on incomplete science.
So my question is, what is the difference in approach that is often taken when reviewing grants compared to journal/conference papers? And how does this change for different scales of grants (e.g. personal fellowship, research projects not funding the investigator's salaries, centers of excellence)?

This is going to be tricky to formulate: there are so many funding agencies, each with its own process, that it's hard to describe what is "often" done.

I'm not a PI, but as a research administrator, I find many PIs don't review the merit review process for the sponsor of their proposal.  As an example, I had a PI who kept getting told there was no expert in topic X on her proposal, and thus it was declined.  She was the expert. Turns out none of the publications on her biosketch covered topic X, thus the investigator score was low.  The "admin docs" matter; they aren't "boilerplate".  PIs get rejected over these docs all the time. Here's NSF's: https://new.nsf.gov/funding/merit-review and NIH's: https://grants.nih.gov/grants/peer-review.htm

A nitpick: It may be just me, but the phrasing in the title mislead me to understand the question to concern "Difference in approach for reviewing [different instances of] papers and grants" (as in how do you consistently evaluate either papers or grants), and as opposed to "Difference in approach for reviewing papers [in general] and grants [in general]".

yeah, I see what you mean, changed the title to make it clearer what I am asking about

You don't begin your experience as a peer reviewer when you get asked to review, you begin it by writing papers and going through the acceptance process, and after a while you understand it enough to start to look at it from the other side. Similarly, you begin your experience in grant review by submitting successful and unsuccessful proposals, and undertaking the research you get funded for.

Arguably, grants are much more important than any given paper because careers are more directly impacted, and should be treated as such by all involved.
My personal policy in paper review is to never write down anything I wouldn't say directly to an author.  Even when the message may not be easy to hear, there are still ways to try to say it nicely.  I don't try to do this with grant reviews, as there's too much on the line to risk the PI not getting the message because I obfuscated it trying to be nice.
Same goes for scoring.  I was in a session once where there was a resubmission where everyone agreed that the PI just missed the point of the review.  Somebody in the room said "how much should we bump the score from the first submission?"  I dug in my heels at giving the PI the same score, as improving it might convince the PI that the study section was not serious about the criticism the PI ignored.  I saw the third submission in study section again (this is back when two resubmissions were allowed at NIH). The PI nailed it, and got one of the best scores that round.
If there's  a clear message you'd like the PI to get, make sure that the scientific review admin understands it well enough to convey it to the PI.
Make sure you know how to generate a score.  A good admin will provide all the necessary training to try to achieve consistency between scorers, and a bad one will not
Judge the science proposed, and not the science you wish was proposed.  There are many ways to skin a cat, and your way may not be the best or only way to get fine results and do stellar science.
Lastly, and most importantly, don't nickel and dime a good proposal you think needs to be funded with a laundry list of minor criticism just so the rest of the room realizes you're smart.  It will lower the scores of everyone in the room.

That last point has a name: new reviewer syndrome

For some grants, no feedback is provided to candidates, supposedly to make it harder for them to challenge the decision in court.

Reviewing a grant application involves assessment of different types of things than reviewing an academic paper.  When reviewing a submitted paper, we are looking at completed research and assessing whether it is ready for publication.  When reviewing a grant application, we are "imagining" a research project that has not yet been done and we are looking primarily at the plan and process for doing that research.  The latter is far more focused on project planning and management for a prospective project rather than trying to assess the quality of an output from a completed project.
Because of the diversity of funding bodies, grant programs, and associated rules and scoring rubrics, there is a great deal of variation in how grant applications are reviewed.  Nevertheless, there are some common aspects of reviews that occur in most cases.  Here are some specific aspects of typical parts of the assessment of a grant application, with comparisons to analogous aspects of reviewing academic papers:

Assessing novelty and prospective value: Assessing a grant application usually involves some initial assessment of the novelty and prospective value of the proposed research.  This is usually assessed relative to the goals of the funding body and there is usually some guidance provided as to the types of projects that are of interest to the funding body.  (Some of the core research funding bodies are interested in virtually every avenue of academic research, but others have much more specialised concerns.)  This aspect of the review is largely analogous to looking at novelty and substantive contribution in a submitted academic paper, including looking at the literature review and research description, and deciding whether the research is "in-scope".  For this part of the review, it is usually useful to separate out questions of feasibility and ask yourself whether the research would be novel and valuable assuming that it could be performed properly (save your concerns about feasibility to a separate part of your review).

Assessing feasibility: Assuming that the application proposes to do something of value, the next question is whether this is feasible.  This aspect of the assessment focusses on approach/methodology and management of the project.  Typically the reviewer will assess whether the proposed method is feasible to implement, whether or not it will actually answer the research question(s) of interest, and whether there are any impediments or problems that could derail the research that have not been considered.  This aspect of the assessment is not a part of the review of academic papers for completed projects, because in that case the research work leading to the output is already completed.

Assessing capability and capacity: Assessing a grant application usually involves some assessment of the capability and capacity of the research group to deliver the research.  This means that you want to ensure that the researchers are qualified to do the research, available to do the research, and that there is sufficient time/budget allocated to the parts of the project.  This is an aspect of the feasibility of the project, but it is focused primarily on skills and resourcing rather than the feasibility of the method itself.

Assessment relative to competition/resources: As with competition between academic papers for space in a journal, there is competition between grant applications for a portion of the grant money available in a funding category.  In both cases there is a finite resource (journal space or grant money) that is to be split between applicants (authors submitting papers or applicants submitting grant proposals).  Therefore, implicit in the assessment of a grant application is a comparison to the general quality of other applications or the level of quality expected for the funding.  This can be thought of as analogous to the implicit consideration of the standard quality and value of submissions in an academic journal.


Here are some useful tips for assessing the quality of a grant application:

Remember that time spent writing grant applications is time not spent producing substantive things of value in academia (e.g., research output, teaching, service).  If reviewers raise their expectations for grant applications too high (e.g., expecting high levels of detail, justification, preliminary research, etc.) then this incentivises more time spent on funding applications, potentially at the derogation of substantive work.  For this reason, it is useful to keep your expectations reasonable and require a general description without excessive detail or preliminary research/analysis.

Remember that a research proposal is not completed research, so try to look at it in a broad holistic sense, without agonising over minor details that can be ironed out once research commences.  If the approach and methodology is fundamentally sensible, and the applicants demonstrate the capability and capacity to perform the research within the time/budget available, that should go a long way towards a positive rating for the application.

Where there are problems with an application, make sure your rating incorporates this but also give clear feedback on the problems so that the applicants can address them in later funding applications.

Don't be one of those bureaucratic arseholes who completely disqualifies an otherwise meritorious grant application because it failed to exactly follow some formal requirement (e.g., it accidentally failed to include some piece of information from a CV).  Doing this elevates form over substance to an excessive degree and wastes the time of researchers.



In addition to existing answers:
Journals typically offer a 'minor revisions' option, and it is normal for reviewers to enumerate every possible way that they think the manuscript might possibly be improved. Often the reviewer doesn't necessarily expect the authors to accept every single suggestion. Apart from verifying that the submission meets some minimum standard, the reviewer's role is to help the author improve their manuscript as much as possible.
Grant programs typically only offer two outcomes: 'accept' or 'revise and resubmit'. Reviews should therefore concentrate on the core ideas of the proposal, and reviewers should be alert to the fact that any (apparently) negative comment may tip the balance towards rejection. This does not mean that your review needs to be wholly positive - if you see weaknesses, you should mention them - but avoid the temptation to highlight issues that are superficial or tangential to the main thrust of the proposal. Apart from verifying that the submission meets some minimum standard, the reviewer's role is to help the panel identify the N most valuable/worthy proposals from within M ( >> N) submissions.
